# Get specific JsonResponse from URL in Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have set up a JsonResponse method in my views.py:

```
def get_rest_list(request):

if request.method == "GET":
    image_list = Image.objects.order_by('-date')
    serializer = ImageSerializer(image_list, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Now if I call that method with "http://localhost:8000/api/" I get a JSON from all Image objects that are in the db.

How can I get a specific object by its pk when I would do something like this: http://localhost:8000/api/1/
or maybe even:
http://localhost:8000/api/445756/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
def get_rest_item(request, image_id):
    image_item = Image.objects.get(id=image_id)
    serializer = ImageSerializer(image_item)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```